# Error while redirecting to custom error page in Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using spring boot and I have created following custom Error Controller to handle errors:

```
@Controller
public class AppErrorController implements ErrorController {

    private static final String PATH = "/error";

    @RequestMapping(value = "/pageNotFound", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
    public String pageNotFound() {
        return "pageNotFound";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/accessDenied", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
    public String accessDenied() {
        return "accessDenied";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = PATH)
    public String error() {
        return "error";
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return PATH;
    }
}
```

When I get an error in the application, it should redirect to custom error pages. Instead I get the following error in the logs and even the error page don't show up:

```
2016-03-09 09:43:21.224 DEBUG 3126 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /error
2016-03-09 09:43:21.224 DEBUG 3126 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public java.lang.String com.sts.app.core.common.web.AppErrorController.error()]
2016-03-09 09:43:21.224 DEBUG 3126 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'appErrorController'
2016-03-09 09:43:21.225 DEBUG 3126 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/gen/error] is: -1
2016-03-09 09:43:21.225 DEBUG 3126 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2016-03-09 09:43:21.227 DEBUG 3126 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'error'
2016-03-09 09:43:21.227 DEBUG 3126 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Rendering view [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$SpelView@5efe80ee] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2016-03-09 09:43:21.235 DEBUG 3126 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Error rendering view [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$SpelView@5efe80ee] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'

org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'timestamp' cannot be found on object of type 'java.util.HashMap' - maybe not public?
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:224) ~[spring-expression-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:94) ~[spring-expression-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:81) ~[spring-expression-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:120) ~[spring-expression-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:242) ~[spring-expression-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$ExpressionResolver.resolvePlaceholder(ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.java:245) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.NonRecursivePropertyPlaceholderHelper$NonRecursivePlaceholderResolver.resolvePlaceholder(NonRecursivePropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:56) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:147) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.NonRecursivePropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(NonRecursivePropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:38) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$SpelView.render(ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.java:194) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1243) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:860) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) [catalina.jar:8.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.21]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-websocket.jar:8.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.21]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:69) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:133) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:113) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:721) [catalina.jar:8.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:466) [catalina.jar:8.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391) [catalina.jar:8.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318) [catalina.jar:8.0.21]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.forwardToErrorPage(ErrorPageFilter.java:188) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.handleException(ErrorPageFilter.java:171) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:135) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:61) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:95) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:113) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219) [catalina.jar:8.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [catalina.jar:8.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [catalina.jar:8.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) [catalina.jar:8.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610) [catalina.jar:8.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [catalina.jar:8.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518) [catalina.jar:8.0.21]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.21]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.21]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.21]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1517) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.21]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1474) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.21]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.21]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]

2016-03-09 09:43:21.236 DEBUG 3126 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2016-03-09 09:43:21.237 DEBUG 3126 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils    : Closing JPA EntityManager
2016-03-09 09:43:21.240 DEBUG 3126 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Could not complete request
```

Below is my `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2" }
        maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-gradle-plugin', version: spring_boot_version
        classpath group: 'org.springframework.build.gradle', name: 'propdeps-plugin', version: propdeps_plugin_version
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'propdeps'
apply from: './gradle/integration_test.gradle'
apply from: './gradle/test_setup.gradle'
apply from: './gradle/code_analysis/code_analysis.gradle'

war {
    baseName = 'gen'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven  {
        url "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2"
    }
}

configurations {
    providedRuntime
}

dependencies {

    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-aop'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    compile(group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web') { exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat' }
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-security'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-taglibs', version: spring_security_version
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-test', version: spring_security_version
    compile group: 'org.springframework.hateoas', name: 'spring-hateoas', version : spring_hateoas_version

    compile group: 'org.jasypt', name: 'jasypt', version: jasypt_version
    compile group: 'org.jasypt', name: 'jasypt-spring31', version: jasypt_spring31_version
    compile group: 'org.jasypt', name: 'jasypt-springsecurity3', version: jasypt_springsecurity3_version

    compile group: 'org.apache.tiles', name: 'tiles-core', version: tiles_version
    compile group: 'org.apache.tiles', name: 'tiles-api', version: tiles_version
    compile group: 'org.apache.tiles', name: 'tiles-jsp', version: tiles_version

    compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'jstl', version: jstl_version

    compile group : 'org.codehaus.janino', name : 'janino', version : janino_version
    compile group: 'javax.inject', name: 'javax.inject', version: javax_inject_version
    /*compile group: 'org.flywaydb', name: 'flyway-core', version: flyway_version*/

    /*compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-envers', version: hibernate_envers_version*/

    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name : 'commons-lang3', version: commons_lang3_version
    compile group: 'commons-fileupload', name : 'commons-fileupload', version: commons_fileupload_version
    compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name : 'poi', version: apache_poi_version

    providedCompile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: servlet_api_version

    runtime('mysql:mysql-connector-java')

    optional group: 'org.springframework.boot', name:'spring-boot-configuration-processor', version: spring_boot_version

    /****************************************************************************/
    /****************** Testing dependencies start below ************************/
    /****************************************************************************/

    testCompile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name:'spring-boot-starter-test'
    testCompile group: 'org.assertj', name: 'assertj-core', version: assertj_version
    testCompile group: 'com.natpryce', name: 'make-it-easy', version: make_it_easy_version
    testCompile group: 'com.ninja-squad', name: 'DbSetup', version: db_setup_version

}

compileJava.dependsOn(processResources)

eclipse {
    classpath {
         containers.remove('org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER')
         containers 'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.7'
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.10'
}
```

Below is my `error.jsp`:

```
<%@ include file="common/taglibs.jsp"%>

System has encountered an error. Please contact your system administrator.
How to solve this issue?
```

Comment: Have you tried to annotate the `AppErrorController` with `@RestController` annotation instead of simple `@Controller`? Or add `@RequestMapping` to the class

Comment: You are trying to access "timestamp" which is on object of type 'java.util.HashMap'.Check your error.html and be sure that  field exists.

Comment: Are you using Spring-Boot-Actuator? I not then try this http://www.sporcic.org/2014/05/custom-error-pages-with-spring-boot.

Comment: @dogankadriye I am using JSP with tiles and I have created error.jsp.

Comment: @Sanjay Rawat I am not using Spring-Boot-Actuator and also I am not using embedded tomcat. I am deploying the application to the external tomcat

Comment: Could you add the error.jsp?

Comment: @fateddy My error.jsp has some static message, nothing else.

Comment: I agree with @fateddy, we need to see your error.jsp file.

Comment: Add your `pom.xml` or `build.gradle`..

Comment: @Ali Dehghani Added the build.gradle

Comment: @Patrick Grimard Added the error.jsp

Comment: Check that all of your versions match.  Spring sometimes goes wonky if you accidentally mix versions.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

### Traditional Deployment

---

If you're not using an embedded servlet container, just disable the white label by adding this to your `application.properties`:

```
server.error.whitelabel.enabled = false
```

### Embedded Tomcat Scenario

---

Add the `tomcat-embed-jasper` as your dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And name your controller as `error`:

```
@Controller("error")
public class AppErrorController implements ErrorController { ... }
```

Or you can disable the white label, instead of renaming the bean:

```
server.error.whitelabel.enabled = false
```

### Why the Name Matters?

---

After a little digging in `ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration` auto configuration, i've encountered with following piece of configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "server.error.whitelabel", name = "enabled", matchIfMissing = true)
@Conditional(ErrorTemplateMissingCondition.class)
protected static class WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration {

    private final SpelView defaultErrorView = new SpelView(
            "<html><body><h1>Whitelabel Error Page</h1>"
                    + "<p>This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.</p>"
                    + "<div id='created'>${timestamp}</div>"
                    + "<div>There was an unexpected error (type=${error}, status=${status}).</div>"
                    + "<div>${message}</div></body></html>");

    @Bean(name = "error")
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "error")
    public View defaultErrorView() {
        return this.defaultErrorView;
    }

    // rest of the configuration
}
```

That timestamp issue is related to `defaultErrorView` of type `SpelView`. So if you register another bean named `error`:

```
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "error")
public View defaultErrorView() { ... }
```

Or disable white label:

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "server.error.whitelabel", name = "enabled", matchIfMissing = true)
```

This view won't be registered and you will avoid that weird exception.

### What About Jasper Dependency?

---

There is a `JspTemplateAvailabilityProvider` that provides availability information for JSP view templates. This class has a `isTemplateAvailable` method that looks like:

```
public boolean isTemplateAvailable(String view, Environment environment,
        ClassLoader classLoader, ResourceLoader resourceLoader) {
    if (ClassUtils.isPresent("org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspConfig", classLoader)) {
        String prefix = getProperty(environment, "spring.mvc.view.prefix",
                "spring.view.prefix", WebMvcAutoConfiguration.DEFAULT_PREFIX);
        String suffix = getProperty(environment, "spring.mvc.view.suffix",
                "spring.view.suffix", WebMvcAutoConfiguration.DEFAULT_SUFFIX);
        return resourceLoader.getResource(prefix + view + suffix).exists();
    }
    return false;
}
```

So if the `org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspConfig` was not present in the classpath, it won't render the jsp view, so we added the required dependency for that, which is `tomcat-embed-jasper`.

Maybe there is a better and less hacky way for this problem but this is the solution i came up with and it is what it is!

Comment: OP is not using embedded Tomcat.

Comment: So what about all the `org.apache.catalina...` logs?

Comment: OP uses Tomcat as a servlet container, and deploys the app to it. So asking them to include `tomcat-embed-jasper` is not the answer.

Comment: So he should just disable the whitelabel, since the `JspConfig` is provided

Comment: Just disabling the whitelabel worked. Thanks. Any idea on adding 404 page in similar way for invalid URL's. In my case it just sows error.jsp all the time. I have added separate question for it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35957040/how-to-show-custom-404-page-when-user-enters-invalid-url-in-spring-boot-applicat

Answer (score 1):

You had many way for managing the error with spring boot. If you read the documentation the official doc say hovewer the best that I used in my projects was of develop a controller for manage the exception and then configure the error page of my tomcat, if you use tomcat but the way was the same for other container. I report a configuration sample:

container configuration:

```
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UserDocumentLibraryClientApplication.class, args);
    }

   ...
    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer exceptionHandling() {
        return container -> container.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage("/exception"));
    }
}
```

controller:

```
@Controller
public class ExceptionController {

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    public void setMessageSource(MessageSource messageSource) {
        this.messageSource = messageSource;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/exception")
    public String exception(Model model,Exception ex,Locale locale,HttpServletRequest httpRequest,HttpServletResponse httpResponse){

        ex.printStackTrace();

        model.addAttribute("templatePath", "exception/exception");
        model.addAttribute("template", "content");
        try{
            model.addAttribute("exceptionMessage",messageSource.getMessage(String.format("exception.body.%s",httpResponse.getStatus()),new Object[]{},locale));
        } catch (NoSuchMessageException e){
            model.addAttribute("exceptionMessage",messageSource.getMessage("exception.body",new Object[]{},locale));
        }
        return "index";
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
...
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
...
```

the index view may be the your thymeleaf template and benefit of the same template of your application.

Of course this is just an example but even in the documentation you can read that if you want a fine grain configuration option this a good options.

I hope that this can help you

Comment: Explicitly linking to the appropriate documentation in the answer would be a nice improvement.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen at the time when I wrote the my answer the my solution was a good way to solve the problem and even to day is a possible solution https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-the-whitelabel-error-page is the link for the motivation of `server.error.whitelabel.enabled`

Comment: however starting from spring boot 1.4 i guess a more advanced error handling was released and for instance we can put custom error page per http status code as descibed on https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-error-handling

Comment: In any case the answare is already fine It is a possible solution for the question