# How to show custom 404 page when user enters invalid URL in spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I am using java config in spring boot, spring security application. I have configured the error controller as below. But whenever, I enter an invalid URL it goes to `error.jsp`, which is configured to handle the errors in the application:

```
@Controller
public class AppErrorController implements ErrorController {

    private static final String PATH = "/error";

    @RequestMapping(value = "/pageNotFound", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
    public String pageNotFound() {
        return "pageNotFound";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/accessDenied", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
    public String accessDenied() {
        return "accessDenied";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = PATH)
    public String error() {
        return "error";
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return PATH;
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/pageNotFound</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/error</location>
</error-page>
```

404 is never thrown when the invalid URL is entered.

Also, I am not using embedded tomcat. I am deploying war to the external tomcat. I have this in my `application.yml` file:

```
server:
    error:
        whitelabel:
            enabled: false
```

Below is the log in case if I enter a invalid URL. There is no error. It just redirects to `/error` in case of invalid URL:

```
2016-03-15 10:02:45.061 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.b.c.web.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@371ef2a3
2016-03-15 10:02:45.061 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/donotexisturl'; against '/static/**'
2016-03-15 10:02:45.061 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/donotexisturl'; against '/i18n/**'
2016-03-15 10:02:45.061 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /doNotExistURL at position 1 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2016-03-15 10:02:45.061 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /doNotExistURL at position 2 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2016-03-15 10:02:45.061 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@b8db0c9d: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@b8db0c9d: Principal: User{id=8, firstname='Adam', lastname='Milne', email='adam.milne@abcd.com', roleId=1}; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffd148a: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: FED1F23633671F6E257CA9C5AFCEE216; Granted Authorities: ModuleOperation{moduleOperationId=1, moduleOperationName='roleList', moduleId=2, moduleName='role'}, ModuleOperation{moduleOperationId=8, moduleOperationName='deleteUser', moduleId=1, moduleName='user'}'
2016-03-15 10:02:45.061 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /doNotExistURL at position 3 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2016-03-15 10:02:45.061 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@6e929f31
2016-03-15 10:02:45.061 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /doNotExistURL at position 4 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
2016-03-15 10:02:45.061 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /doNotExistURL at position 5 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2016-03-15 10:02:45.061 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /donotexisturl' doesn't match 'POST /logout
2016-03-15 10:02:45.061 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /doNotExistURL at position 6 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
2016-03-15 10:02:45.061 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /donotexisturl' doesn't match 'POST /checklogin
2016-03-15 10:02:45.062 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /doNotExistURL at position 7 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ConcurrentSessionFilter'
2016-03-15 10:02:45.062 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /doNotExistURL at position 8 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2016-03-15 10:02:45.062 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /doNotExistURL at position 9 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2016-03-15 10:02:45.062 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /doNotExistURL at position 10 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2016-03-15 10:02:45.062 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@b8db0c9d: Principal: User{id=8, firstname='Adam', lastname='Milne', email='adam.milne@abcd.com', roleId=1}; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffd148a: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: FED1F23633671F6E257CA9C5AFCEE216; Granted Authorities: ModuleOperation{moduleOperationId=1, moduleOperationName='roleList', moduleId=2, moduleName='role'}, ModuleOperation{moduleOperationId=8, moduleOperationName='deleteUser', moduleId=1, moduleName='user'}'
2016-03-15 10:02:45.062 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /doNotExistURL at position 11 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2016-03-15 10:02:45.062 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /doNotExistURL at position 12 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2016-03-15 10:02:45.062 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /doNotExistURL at position 13 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2016-03-15 10:02:45.062 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /donotexisturl' doesn't match 'POST /logout
2016-03-15 10:02:45.062 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/donotexisturl'; against '/login**'
2016-03-15 10:02:45.062 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/donotexisturl'; against '/error**'
2016-03-15 10:02:45.062 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/donotexisturl'; against '/checklogin**'
2016-03-15 10:02:45.062 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /doNotExistURL; Attributes: [fullyAuthenticated]
2016-03-15 10:02:45.062 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@b8db0c9d: Principal: User{id=8, firstname='Adam', lastname='Milne', email='adam.milne@abcd.com', roleId=1}; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffd148a: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: FED1F23633671F6E257CA9C5AFCEE216; Granted Authorities: ModuleOperation{moduleOperationId=1, moduleOperationName='roleList', moduleId=2, moduleName='role'}, ModuleOperation{moduleOperationId=8, moduleOperationName='deleteUser', moduleId=1, moduleName='user'}
2016-03-15 10:02:45.062 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased  : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@6ad88564, returned: 1
2016-03-15 10:02:45.062 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased  : Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter@19007bb6, returned: 0
2016-03-15 10:02:45.062 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased  : Voter: com.sts.app.core.user.security.AccessDecisionVoterImpl@1465b821, returned: 1
2016-03-15 10:02:45.062 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorization successful
2016-03-15 10:02:45.062 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
2016-03-15 10:02:45.062 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /doNotExistURL reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2016-03-15 10:02:45.062 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/gen/doNotExistURL]
2016-03-15 10:02:45.063 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /doNotExistURL
2016-03-15 10:02:45.064 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/doNotExistURL]
2016-03-15 10:02:45.064 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Matching patterns for request [/doNotExistURL] are [/**]
2016-03-15 10:02:45.064 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : URI Template variables for request [/doNotExistURL] are {}
2016-03-15 10:02:45.064 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapping [/doNotExistURL] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[ServletContext resource [/], class path resource [META-INF/resources/], class path resource [resources/], class path resource [static/], class path resource [public/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@87dd2cb]]] and 1 interceptor
2016-03-15 10:02:45.064 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/gen/doNotExistURL] is: -1
2016-03-15 10:02:45.077 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2016-03-15 10:02:45.078 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
2016-03-15 10:02:45.078 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally
2016-03-15 10:02:45.078 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2016-03-15 10:02:45.078 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.b.c.web.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@371ef2a3
2016-03-15 10:02:45.078 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.b.c.web.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@20ae74b1
2016-03-15 10:02:45.078 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/static/**'
2016-03-15 10:02:45.078 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/i18n/**'
2016-03-15 10:02:45.078 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 1 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2016-03-15 10:02:45.078 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 2 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2016-03-15 10:02:45.078 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@b8db0c9d: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@b8db0c9d: Principal: User{id=8, firstname='Adam', lastname='Milne', email='adam.milne@abcd.com', roleId=1}; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffd148a: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: FED1F23633671F6E257CA9C5AFCEE216; Granted Authorities: ModuleOperation{moduleOperationId=1, moduleOperationName='roleList', moduleId=2, moduleName='role'}, ModuleOperation{moduleOperationId=8, moduleOperationName='deleteUser', moduleId=1, moduleName='user'}'
2016-03-15 10:02:45.078 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 3 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2016-03-15 10:02:45.078 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 4 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
2016-03-15 10:02:45.078 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 5 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2016-03-15 10:02:45.078 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /error' doesn't match 'POST /logout
2016-03-15 10:02:45.078 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 6 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
2016-03-15 10:02:45.078 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /error' doesn't match 'POST /checklogin
2016-03-15 10:02:45.079 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 7 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ConcurrentSessionFilter'
2016-03-15 10:02:45.079 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 8 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2016-03-15 10:02:45.079 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 9 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2016-03-15 10:02:45.079 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 10 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2016-03-15 10:02:45.079 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@b8db0c9d: Principal: User{id=8, firstname='Adam', lastname='Milne', email='adam.milne@abcd.com', roleId=1}; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffd148a: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: FED1F23633671F6E257CA9C5AFCEE216; Granted Authorities: ModuleOperation{moduleOperationId=1, moduleOperationName='roleList', moduleId=2, moduleName='role'}, ModuleOperation{moduleOperationId=8, moduleOperationName='deleteUser', moduleId=1, moduleName='user'}'
2016-03-15 10:02:45.079 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 11 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2016-03-15 10:02:45.079 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 12 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2016-03-15 10:02:45.079 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 13 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2016-03-15 10:02:45.079 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2016-03-15 10:02:45.079 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/gen/error]
2016-03-15 10:02:45.079 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /error
2016-03-15 10:02:45.079 DEBUG 9997 --- [io-8080-exec-22] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public java.lang.String com.sts.app.core.common.web.AppErrorController.error()]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, define an exception for each especial HTTP error you're going to handle. Here i'm just defining one for handling `404 Not Found` case:

```
public class NotFoundException extends RuntimeException {}
```

To replace the default Spring Boot's error handling mechanism completely, we can implement `ErrorController`. Instead of just implementing the `ErrorController`, here i'm extending `AbstractErrorController`, which implements the `ErrorController` and provides some auxiliary methods like `getStatus()`.

Anyway, the basic idea is to handle all errors using an endpoint, say `/error`, and throw those pre-defined exceptions in case of their corresponding HTTP status codes:

```
@Controller
public class CustomErrorController extends AbstractErrorController {
    private static final String ERROR_PATH=  "/error";

    @Autowired
    public CustomErrorController(ErrorAttributes errorAttributes) {
        super(errorAttributes);
    }

    /**
     * Just catching the {@linkplain NotFoundException} exceptions and render
     * the 404.jsp error page.
     */
    @ExceptionHandler(NotFoundException.class)
    public String notFound() {
        return "404";
    }

    /**
     * Responsible for handling all errors and throw especial exceptions
     * for some HTTP status codes. Otherwise, it will return a map that
     * ultimately will be converted to a json error.
     */
    @RequestMapping(ERROR_PATH)
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleErrors(HttpServletRequest request) {
        HttpStatus status = getStatus(request);

        if (status.equals(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND))
            throw new NotFoundException();

        return ResponseEntity.status(status).body(getErrorAttributes(request, false));
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return ERROR_PATH;
    }
}
```

Of course, this solution is only suitable for *Traditional Deployment*. If you're planning to use an Embedded Servlet Container, you're better off defining an `EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer`.

Answer (score 3):

Whould you like to add this `@Bean` to your spring application config, like this :

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer() {
    return new EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer() {
        @Override
        public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {

            ErrorPage error404Page = new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/error404.html");
            container.addErrorPages(error404Page);

        }
    };
}
```

and put `error404.html` in your static folder.

Reference :
http://www.sporcic.org/2014/05/custom-error-pages-with-spring-boot/

Comment: I am not using embedded tomcat. Will this still apply?

Comment: What excpetion do you get when your remove the error pages in your web.xml.Probably Spring is throwing another exception wihich is not 404 due to a setup error. Post the error being displayed on tomcat`s default error page

Comment: Ironically that link is now dead.

Comment: EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer is not available in Spring Boot 2

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
@RestController
public class RestErrorController implements ErrorController{

private static final String PATH = "/error";

@Autowired
private ErrorAttributes errorAttributes;

@RequestMapping(value=PATH,method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ApiErrorExtended error(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
     return new ApiErrorExtended( response.getStatus(),getErrorAttributes(request, true));
}

private Map<String, Object> getErrorAttributes(HttpServletRequest request, boolean includeStackTrace) {
    RequestAttributes requestAttributes = new ServletRequestAttributes(request);
    return errorAttributes.getErrorAttributes(requestAttributes, includeStackTrace);
}  

public String getErrorPath() {
    return PATH;
} 
}
```

This is my rest error controller. You can modify it to return whatever u want.

Comment: Try value=404 instead /pageNotFound see if that helps
edited : value = /error

Comment: Did u try removing  `<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/pageNotFound</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/error</location>
</error-page>`
all together? I believe 404 will be resolved by default.
Anyways i am gonna take a closer look at my config. when i get back to my pc.

Answer (score 0):

hi，you only need to configure the following:

```
<error-page>
     <error-code>404</error-code>
     <location>/pageNotFound/404.jsp</location>
 </error-page>
```

and you configure the Java exception:

```
<error-page>
 <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
 <location>/pageNotFound/exception.jsp</location>
```

Comment: I have tried that also. Does not work. Actually, it used to work in other non spring boot apps.

Answer (score 0):

For applications that do not use Spring MVC, you can use the ErrorPageRegistrar interface to directly register ErrorPages:

```
import org.springframework.boot.web.server.ErrorPage;
import org.springframework.boot.web.server.ErrorPageRegistrar;
import org.springframework.boot.web.server.ErrorPageRegistry;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;

@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class MyErrorPagesConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ErrorPageRegistrar errorPageRegistrar() {
        return this::registerErrorPages;
    }

    private void registerErrorPages(ErrorPageRegistry registry) {
        registry.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "/400.html"));
    }

}
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#web.servlet.spring-mvc.error-handling.error-pages-without-spring-mvc