# How to make an invalid url in spring boot to return JSON response instead of index.html

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

i want to make my application to return JSON instead of html response when trying to get localhost:8080, but i cannot achieve the desired result because this is before the

```
 servlet:
    context-path: /v0
```

and everything before "/v0" is returning index.html

I want everything before "/v0" to return something like this:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2022-12-01T12:59:51.832+00:00",
  "status": 404,
  "error": "Not Found",
  "path": "/"
}
```

I tried to add this in my @ControllerAdvice

```
@ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> unhandledPath(Exception e) {
  Map<String, Object> errorInfo = new LinkedHashMap<>();
  errorInfo.put("timestamp", new Date());
  errorInfo.put("httpCode", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value());
  errorInfo.put("httpStatus", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.getReasonPhrase());
  errorInfo.put("errorMessage", e.getMessage());
  return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(errorInfo, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
```

But it does't return the json instead returns this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlxiQ.png

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35957040/how-to-show-custom-404-page-when-user-enters-invalid-url-in-spring-boot-applicat

Comment: Hello, i tried it but it doesn't work :(